# SQL date "0001-01-01" to date format before insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this value from another script in my code, when there is no data, it comes as '0001-01-01'. I would like if its possible to convert this string '0001-01-01' into a date format "datetime" in my SQL insert line before adding it to another table. Here is how I am trying, but no success:

```
my $sql = $dbh->exec_sql(<<SQL, $address, $name, $dateadded);
insert into mytable (address, name, dateadded)
values (?,?, Case When ? = '0001-01-01' then '0001-01-01 00:00:00' Else ?)
SQL
```

Thanks!

Comment: you need a valid timestamp value.  Both of these are not.  SQL provides null for situations like this... I recommend using it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because this is not a valid date in sql server. Sql server consider dates between 1753-01-01 and 9999-12-31. Check this link for more information: ["DATETIME"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

Use a NULL value instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
insert into my table (address, name, dateadded) 
values (?, ?, CASE WHEN ISDATE(?)=1 THEN ? ELSE NULL END)
```

You can substitute `NULL` for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` etc if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into my table (address, name, dateadded) values (?, ?, convert(datetime, ?))
```

Comment: It doesn't work because sqlserver sees this date as an invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add that date as it is, but you can put `NULL` there.

Try this logic:

```
declare @mystr varchar(50)
set @mystr = '0001.01.01'
select
    case
        when isdate(@mystr) = 1
        then @mystr
        else ''
    end
```

There is a function [`try_convert`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx), introduced in SQL 2012. If you are using that version, you can try that.

**UPDATE**

I am adding another example:

```
declare @TheDate datetime
set @TheDate =
    case 
        when isdate('0001.01.01') = 1 
        then '0001.01.01' 
        else cast(null as datetime) 
    end --null will be stored
-- OR Use this instead
set @TheDate = 
    case 
        when isdate('0001.01.01') = 1 
        then '0001.01.01'
        else ''
    end --1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 will be stored
select @TheDate
```

Then you can do this:

```
insert into mytable 
    (address, name, dateadded)
values 
    (?, ?, 
        case when isdate('0001.01.01') = 1 then '0001.01.01' else '' end
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **datetime** because it must be in the range 17530101 - 99991231, use **datetime2**  data type for your column instead.

Plus, it is better to use CONVERT for your date string (canonical date format is recognized with char constants and this is not mandatory), like in the following:

```
insert into MyTable (...MyDate ...) values ( ... convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01 00:00:00', 120) ...)
```

see CONVERT documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms187928.aspx) for format specification (the third parameter of convert)